# Why global variables are there in C++?

Tags: c++, global-variables

If you are using proper OOP concepts, I do not got any use case where global variables are actually needed and in my application I have not used any global variable and able to achieve everything efficiently using object oriented principles.

Each class has it's own responsibility, so I was wondering why to use global variables.

Can someone please point me any use case where using global variables is really required?

Comment: A common global variable is `std::cout`...

Comment: C++ is designed to transcend fashions such as OOP. That doesn't lead to global variables being useful or not, but it indicates that "with OOP you do this" is not a relevant argument for many C++ design decisions.

Comment: public static variable in class == global variable.    
private static variable in class == internal linkage global variable.    

If you feel you need to use one, you can use other the same way.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, Perfectly stated.  The guys of the Java and C# background mock of other languages' global variables without even stopping to think that their many static stuff is just the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a Java/C# biased approach. global variable can be usefull sometimes when the entire program needs to be familiar with shared data.

Although Java and C# clearly states that "global variables are not needed, everything should reside inside a class" - the existance of "Utils" and "Helpers" classes in just about every managed project  clearly shows the opposite.

Cases that come into mind:

- Global usefull macros like `EOF`
- Global streams like `std::cout` and `std::cin`
- the program's current Locale
- The process' Heap pointer

Of course, finding appropriate class or namespace is highly recomended, but not mandatory.

Also, I highly confused about the term "proper OOP concepts". "proper" is language specific. thing that may be proper in one language, are clearly not "proper" in another language.

Comment: I was wondering if cpp lacks some language feature because of which we need to use global vars

Comment: if there is one language that does not suffer lack of features, is the CPP language :) so no.

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting a new project which is developed entirely in C++, global variables are entirely unnecessary. They can be replaced by class-static variables, and variables with namespace visibility.

The only reason the truly global variables remain in the language is that they are available in C, of which C++ is a direct descendant. [According to Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#difference),

> C++ is "a better C" in the sense that it supports the styles of programming done using C with better type checking and more notational support (without loss of efficiency).

That's why the facility of global variables has not been removed from the language.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that global variables are sometimes awkward is that it can be hard to track down every place where they are modified. Giving them a more complicated name (i.e., by writing them as static variables inside a class, a la Java) doesn't change that. Global variables (by whatever mechanism) remove the need to pass state information that's used throughout a program to functions that don't need it themselves but call other functions, directly or indirectly, that do need it. This clutter is known as "tramp data", and is in many ways worse than global data.

Comment: A good and informative answer, but doesn't answer the question.